# How can I append undeletable value in input form?

Tags: html, input

I'm trying to do something exactly like this [sign up form here](https://www.timeclockwizard.com/sign-up/). They have appended their domain name as undeletable value to allow user to create a sub domain folder. I want to do the same with following input:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control inputlogin" name="subdomain_name" placeholder="Sub Domain" required="" value=""/>
```

I found a technique [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J2BKU/) but I'm not looking to append a prefix. The value must be after like in the example.

Comment: Uhm... even if you set the value, an end user could still change it

Comment: So open source code of example provided and do the same

Comment: Don't use that value in your input field, just show to the user and do some work on the backend to append that value again.

Comment: That's a bootstrap thing. Look at the HTML source and go from there, or visit http://getbootstrap.com/ and go through the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a styling trick. `input` are either completely editable or disabled (not editable at all). There is no way to get around this.

What is done in the form you linked to is a trick where the "frozen" text is placed upon the input field so it looks as if it is a part of the actual input tag, but it is not.

Se [my simple jsfiddle illustration](https://jsfiddle.net/ds1v3w8L/). Look at how the styling can be used to create the illusion you want.

Comment: Very Neat. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Bootstrap 3:

[Bootstrap 3 Sub-domain input](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29880/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your sub-domaion here">
    <span class="input-group-addon" title="Type of Question">.our-domain.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```